# Can't reliably create a directory on startup after ec2 instance mounts it's ephemeral drives

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

This particular instance type mounts two ephemeral drives, in /dev/ and /mnt/. I have to create working directories for one of my services in these paths at startup or the services won't launch. Sometimes this script below works, sometimes it does not. I suspect it's a race between the folder being mounted, and my rc.local script kicking off. Is there a more reliable place I can create these directories? The last time I booted up, the /mnt/mongodb dir did get created, but the /dev/ one did not. I'm running the 12.04 HVM ubuntu instance from amazon.

Here is my rc.local file:

```
cd /mnt/
sudo mkdir mongodb
sudo chown -R mongodb mongodb
sudo chgrp -R mongodb mongodb
cd /dev/
sudo mkdir mongodb
sudo chown -R mongodb mongodb
sudo chgrp -R mongodb mongodb
sudo service mongodb start
exit 0
```

Comment: Putting a working directory under /dev/ is an extremely odd practice.  That directory is reserved for system devices.  I doubt /dev/ is ephemeral unless something odd is going on.

Comment: Leave `/dev` untouched.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer removing /dev section of the script and using /mnt/mongodb for logs still doesn't solve the race condition that we're encountering. /mnt isn't always mounted before the rc.local is executed. I will however take the advice about avoiding using /dev for logging.